# How to create a byte[] of gz file in php as like in C#

Tags: php, arrays, soap-client

I create one gz file and it contains a XML.
Now I want to create a byte[] for that gz file. how it possible?

> **HOW TO CREATE byte[] as like in C#**
>
> **HOW TO PASS THAT ARRAY IN SOAP CLIENT IN php**

I tried these code to

```
 $byteArray  = pack('a',file_get_contents($gzfile));
```

How it possible ? thanks in advance.

> Why I do this I want to pass the binary data of gz file into soap
> service parameter

Comment: There is no such thing as "binary data", at least no precise definition. So what do you mean by that. What exactly do you want to create?

Comment: Which did not answer my question. What do you mean by "binary data" or now "byte code"? _All_ data in a digital computer system is "byte code".

Comment: There's absolutely no effort done on your part to make anything even close to a SOAP call to anything. You can't just expect a full tutorial on [how SOAP works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) from us.

Comment: No answer to clear questions => nothing we can help with.

Comment: base64Binary xmldata ; __getTypes() show a function with parameter of this type?